# How can I get small parts of Cyanogenmod like sound files?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Is there an easy way to get parts of Cyanogen Mod, for example the sound files? I'm sure that I can probably pull the source and download individual elements (pictures, sound files, etc) but this seems time consuming and potentially difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it, use CyanogenMod's [github](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/tree/jellybean/data) - for reference - this applies across the board whether with AOSP, CAF, CM, AOKP, its found in `frameworks/base/data`.

Comment: You have to go to "downloads" and then download the whole thing, then you can cherry pick what you want from the archive.

Comment: not necessarily, the OP can clone just the android_frameworks_base to their PC and can get at the data directory. There is no other way of doing it :)